# How to search LinkedList with some initial value of string present under it?

Tags: java

I have got a LinkedList as shown below

```
   package com;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import org.json.JSONException;
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add("Apple(7)");
        list.add("Bucket(2)");
        String strtosearch = "Bucket";
    }
}
```

I am trying to search the LinkedList this way , If i provide a value Bucket , i needed the value 2 .

If i provide Apple then it must return 7

Is there any easy  way of doing this ??

I know of String.StartsWith can help , but is there any other way of doing this ??

Comment: Consider using a HashMap instead.

Comment: How can a HashMap help ??

Comment: By allowing you to get a `value` given a certain `key`. Read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrone data structure for such tasks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashMapDemo {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      HashMap hm = new HashMap();
      hm.put( "Apple", 7);
      hm.put( "Bucket", 2);

      System.out.println( hm.get("Apple") );

 }
```

Comment: Thanks , but i dont want to use HashMap as there is some big story behind storing data in LinkedList in this format .

Comment: so you are stuck with simple looping and checking.